# Getting rid of underfull vbox warnings when using clearpage

Tags: vertical-alignment, white-space, clearpage

Whenever I use a `\clearpage` command in my document it is because I want to force a new page and leave whitespace at the bottom of the previous page. However, TeX doesn't like this, and gives me `underfull \vbox` warnings everywhere.

I can get around this using the `\raggedbottom` command, but that relaxes the constraint globally and I don't want that since it allows TeX to get lazy about float placements and results in some ugly whitespace where I don't want it. Is there a way to tweak `\clearpage` so that it also applies a local relaxed constraint on the vertical fit which applies only to the page being cleared?

Comment: the default definition of `\clearpage` will not give underfull vbox warnings, so there is something you are not telling us, please provide an example that shows the problem so it can be debugged. Also `\raggedbottom` and `\flushbottom` do not affect float placement with the usual definitions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle strange, I will have to dig into this more in order to produce a MWE.